# How to say $!n$ out loud

Tags: soft-question, factorial, derangements, pronunciation

Is there a common way to pronounce the expression $!n$ for the number of derangements of $n$ objects, other than "The number of derangements of $n$ objects?"  Something like "factorial $n$" or "bang $n$" perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for asking this!  But my guess is the answer is "there is no agreed upon way to say this."  Hope I am wrong.

Comment: If you mean  "n!" rather than "!n" then it is "n factorial".

Comment: @user247327 No, he is referencing the subfactorial function, which counts the derangements of n objects. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html

Comment: @lulu: I think you are probably right. I quite like "shriek n", but I don't think there's general a greement on this or any of the suggestions in the question.

Comment: In some languages ! denotes a click...

Comment: @RobArthan Here's hoping "shriek $n$" catches on.

Comment: @RobArthan  That one hadn't occurred to me, but I am all in on it.  Shreik $n$ it is.

Comment: Said four times each time the refrain is sung:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBJVVhn7iuo

Comment: Heh, not only do I agree with @lulu that there is no agreed-on convention for pronouncing $!n$, but in my experience, $!n$ is not even agreed-on notation for the number of derangements of $n$. I've seen it, but I see something like $D_n$ more often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say "subfactorial n".

Comment: Or would you say "n subfactorial"? I don't believe there is an agreed way of saying this expression.

Comment: Do you have references that utilize this pronunciation? I think the OP wants something that is common and having a few references would go a long ways toward showing it's a common usage.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gxrO8ZnMK_YC&pg=RA1-PA77&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I looked at that Wikipedia article, and completely missed the term.  Thank you.